# '/snap/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable

Tags: ubuntu, path

I am trying to install flutter on Ubuntu and when i ran flutter, i got following error

```
Command 'flutter' is available in '/snap/bin/flutter'
The command could not be located because '/snap/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
flutter: command not found
```

Here is my `/etc/environment` file

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
```

I think `snap/bin` is in PATH. I have tried restarting the system and also tried `source /etc/environment`, But still i am unable to start flutter.

If i do `source /etc/environment` the flutter command work, but only in that terminal, if tried it again after closing terminal or open a new terminal, It didnot worked